# Flushing buffer to stdout in production server of flask app

Tags: docker, flask, logging, buffer, stdout

I am running a flask app, and trying to flush to the stdout of a process to a log file in real time. When I run my dockerized app in development mode (ENV FLASK_ENV=development), it works just fine. My stdout gets flushed to the log file I'm writing too almost immediately and it works great.

```
with open("./logs/log.txt", "wb") as f:
        with stdio_proxy.redirect_stdout(f):
            print("code whose stdout I want in the logs goes here")
```

Note: I am using `stdio_proxy.redirect_stdout` because this is occurring in a thread (specifically a `multiprocessing.Process`), and `stdio_proxy.redirect_stdout` is the only way I could find to redirect the stdout in a thread-safe manner.

However, when I deploy my dockerized flask app to my AWS Lightsail server or set the `ENV FLASK_ENV=production`, the stdout stops getting flushed to the logs immediately. Instead, it takes several minutes or until a bunch of stuff gets written, at which point I'm assuming the buffer fills up, and buffer gets pushed to stdout which gets redirected to my log file.

I have tried several potential solutions I've seen, including:

- Adding the `-u` flag to my python script `CMD exec python3 -u app.py`
- Setting `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` in my dockerfile
- calling `sys.stdout.flush()` to flush the buffer to stdout

TLDR: Why is flushing the buffer to stdout different in production than development, and how do I flush it more regularly

Answer (score 0):

It appears my issue didn't actually have anything to do with flushing the buffer to the stdout. The problem was that the stdout was getting routed to another buffer that gets flushed to the log file, and this second buffer was the one that wasn't flushing. All I had to do was add `buffering=0` to my command to open the file. I guess the production server was using different size file buffers than the development server.

```
with open("./logs/log.txt", "wb", buffering=0) as f:
        with stdio_proxy.redirect_stdout(f):
            print("code whose stdout I want in the logs goes here")
```